# Нужно ли делать составной первичный ключ?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

[image: Таблица room_service]

Я не могу понять, нужно ли делать составной первичный ключ ({room_serviceID, roomNumber})? Сейчас в таблице room_service ПК - room_serviceID. Мне это важно для приведения данной таблицы к НФБК

Comment: Это зависит от того, для чего используется эта таблица. Если для одного room_serviceID может быть несколько разных roomNumber и именно эта пара вместе уникально идентифицирует запись, то возможно и стоит сделать первичный ключ таким. Если же это не так, то такой первичный ключ нельзя делать ни в коем случае

Comment: @Mike, столбец room_serviceID автоинкрементируемый, так что он не может быть повторяющимся. Получается нужно оставить простой первичный ключ? Если так, то service_id не зависит от roomNumber? Чтобы не было транзитивных зависимостей и можно привести к НФБК

Comment: Да, конечно простой. А где вы тут видите транзитивные зависимости ?

Comment: @Mike, room_serviceID->roomNumber->service_id. У меня просто есть сомнение что id услуги в номере (service_id) зависит от номера отеля.

Comment: Я зависимостей не вижу. room_serviceID вообще в этом ключе не рассматривается, потому что он уникален и  случае у него не может быть зависимостей ни от чего. Я не вижу в примере данных что бы service_id как то зависел от roomNumber